# Understanding :after and :before

Tags: css, css-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/BtGRt/

Why contents are appearing inside div? Not on the left/right (before/after) the div?

Comment: Because that's what the spec says.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content), you can see that they are inserted in respect to the content not the element.

> As their names indicate, the :before and :after pseudo-elements
> specify the **location of content before and after an element's document
> tree content**.
>
> The :before and :after pseudo-elements **inherit any inheritable
> properties from the element**
> in the document tree to which they are
> attached.
>
> For example, the following rules insert an open quote mark before
> every Q element. The color of the quote mark will be red, but the font
> will be the same as the font of the rest of the Q element:
>
> q:before {   content: open-quote;   color: red }

Comment: `background` [is not inheritable](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-color). You should remove everything in your answer before "Also from the spec".

Comment: Not *inherited* by default, until you explicitly specify `background-color: inherit`, but that's beside the point...

Comment: @thirtydot totally not what I meant by the first sentence.  It's poorly worded as I was just referring to the div containing everything and wasn't referring to styling.  I bolded the spec stuff after I put everything in and didn't think about placement.

Answer (score 3):

Because `:after` and `:before` don't add psuedoelements after or before the element to which they are attached; they add them after or before that element's *content*.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3aafter) for technical detail - the generated elements are the last / first *child* of the matched element.

Answer (score 0):

When you combine 'content' with :after and :before, it adds the content before or after the existing content. So, within the div. If you want it parse the additions around the div as a whole, you'd need something like

```
<div id="w">
 <div id="f">World </div>
</div>


#w:before{    
background: yellowgreen;
content: "Hello ";
}
#f{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: gold;
margin: 100px;
padding: 100px;
}
#w:after{    
background: burlywood;
content: "StackOverflow";
}
```